# User defined arguments in Boost Phoenix

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

The Boost Phoenix documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/primitives.html#phoenix.primitives.arguments.user_defined_arguments) indicates that I can create my own (lambda) arguments instead of `_1`/`arg1`, `_2`,`arg2` etc. So, starting with code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << (boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1)(17) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

...which outputs `17`, I'm aiming for a first step of using `myarg1`. The documentation recommends that I first `#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/argument.hpp>`. Doing this (G++ 4.7.2), however, results in a series of compilation errors starting with: **error: redefinition of ‘struct boost::phoenix::detail::error_expecting_arguments’**.

*Without* the arguments.hpp file included, I notice that I can declare variables of type `boost::phoenix::argument<0>`. When I try to declare a variable of the crucial type, `boost::phoenix::actor< boost::phoenix::argument<0> >`, however, I again receive numerous errors; this time starting with: **error: no type named ‘proto_base_expr’**. How can I define my own lambda arguments?

Comment: You can use 2 versions of phoenix which are incompatible with each other. v2 lives in `boost/spirit/home/phoenix`, v3 in `boost/phoenix`. If you try to mix headers you get redefinition errors. So the header you wanted to use is `boost/phoenix/core/argument.hpp` and that one is included when you use the global include. In order to declare an actor you can use `phx:actor<phx::expression::argument<N>::type> my_actor` where N is the position of the argument you want to use starting at 1. Maybe `my_actor` should be declared const but, in my limited testing, it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Thanks @llonesmiz! I missed your comment about starting at 1, but now it works fine. If anyone would like to provide that as an answer, they can receive the points.

Comment: @llonesmiz : `const` allows for static initialization since the types involved are all POD types. I.e., it's a harmless micro-optimization.

Comment: `phx::expression::argument<N>::type` also works, and allows me to use the subscript operator; as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397899/subscript-operator-error-with-boost-c-phoenix-user-defined-argument). Is there a disadvantage to this?