# Subscript operator[] error with Boost C++ Phoenix user-defined argument

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

With an existing Boost Phoenix (placeholder) argument, such as `_1`, I can use the array/subscript operator. For example, the following excerpt will display a `1`.

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
std::cout << _1[0](arr) << std::endl;
```

However, if I define my own placeholder argument:

```
phoenix::actor<phoenix::expression::argument<1>::type> const my_1 = {{}};
```

though it works fine unadorned (the following outputs a 7):

```
std::cout << my_1(7) << std::endl;
```

if I attempt to use the subscript operator (as above):

```
std::cout << my_1[0](arr) << std::endl;
```

I get many errors; in summary, with G++ 4.7.2, template argument deduction fails; with Clang 3.2, I'm told that a function cannot return an array type.

How can I make my Phoenix placeholder argument support the subscript operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get rid of the `actor` part and it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

    phx::expression::argument<1>::type const my_1 = {{{}}};
    int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << my_1[0](arr) << '\n';
}
```

<sub>[Online demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/24eNCC%244)</sub>

Comment: I see `decltype(phx::arg_names::_1)` also works, although the type is apparently `const type`. Strangely, so is that of `decltype(phx::arg_names::_2)`.

Comment: @user2023370 : The declaration of `phx::arg_names::_1` is identical to that of `my_1` other than the scope in which it resides, so I certainly hope that would work. ;-]

Comment: Ok. It's just that I found this failed: `static_assert(std::is_same<phx::expression::argument<1>::type,decltype(phx::arg_names::_1)>::value,"");`

Comment: @user2023370 : Right, it's the `const`, as you mentioned. The following would all work: `static_assert(std::is_same<phx::expression::argument<1>::type const, decltype(phx::arg_names::_1)>::value, "");` or `static_assert(std::is_same<phx::expression::argument<1>::type, std::remove_const<decltype(phx::arg_names::_1)>::type>::value, "");` or `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(phx::arg_names::_1), decltype(my_1)>::value, "");`.